# Registry variable(%1) passed to cmd when used in cmd doesn't display full path(doen't included text with spaces)

Tags: cmd, registry

In a registry key I passed %1 to lockfolder.bat as:

**D:\folder\lockfolder.bat %1**

This runs the batch file with the %1 argument

but when in the above cmd file I use %1,the file contains:

**cmd /c echo %1**

*if %1 is a path with spaces say, "d:\hello world" then cmd just accepts d:\hello
but works fine for say "d:\games" which has no space*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert at top of batch file `D:\folder\lockfolder.bat` following lines:

```
@echo off
echo Windows called this batch file with the command line:
echo/
echo %0 %*
echo/
echo Batch argument string: %0
echo Batch arg. no quotes:  %~0
echo Batch argument drive:  %~d0
echo Batch argument path:   %~dp0
echo Batch argument name:   %~n0
echo Batch argument ext.:   %~x0
echo Batch arg. name+ext.:  %~nx0
echo Batch argument full:   %~f0
echo Batch argument time:   %~t0
if "%~1" == "" goto BatPause
echo/
echo First argument string: %1
echo First arg. no quotes:  %~1
echo First argument drive:  %~d1
echo First argument path:   %~dp1
echo First argument name:   %~n1
echo First argument ext.:   %~x1
echo First arg. name+ext.:  %~nx1
echo First argument full:   %~f1
echo First argument time:   %~t1
:BatPause
echo/
pause
```

On right clicking on folder `D:\hello world` the batch file should output with line `echo %0 %*`:

```
D:\folder\lockfolder.bat "D:\hello world"
```

In case of both `"` are missing resulting in calling the batch file with `D:\hello` as first argument and `world` as second argument, change in Windows registry the command to:

```
D:\folder\lockfolder.bat "%1"
```

Then the batch file should be executed with folder path always enclosed in double quotes resulting in first argument string being `"D:\hello world"` which can be processed as demonstrated by the command lines above in the batch file.

Open a command prompt window and run `call /?` for an explanation of all those argument references used in this demo batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Always use quotes for paths and filenames. The TILDE removes quotes that might have been there and does no damage if they are not.

```
D:\folder\lockfolder.bat "%~1"

cmd /c echo "%~1"
```

Comment: It still ain't working might be some problem with the code on the registry key value: D:\folder\lockfolder.bat **%1**     Maybe the %1 here has something to do with the error.....I've tried almost everything

Comment: Be sure to use quoting on the invocation of the .bat file script.

Comment: did it.Still doesn't work.I guess there is some problem with the code on the registry key value

Comment: What is the actual registry path, name, type, and value.

Comment: **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Lock\command**   ,I created a key lock in shell folder which has a key command with default value **D:\folder\lockfolder.bat %1** ,"%~1" didn't seem to work here